# LinkedHashMap with Castor

Tags: java, xml, hashmap, linkedhashmap, castor

How can I tell Castor to use a LinkedHashMap instead of a HashMap?

Comment: Where does the castor library use HashMap? Why do you want to replace it by LinkedHashMap?

Comment: Can you post some related code?

Comment: In the marshalling and unmarshalling of an object that contains a LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

A cursory glance at http://www.castor.org/reference/html-single/index.html tells me this "The type of the object inside the collection is . The 'default implementation' is the type used if the object holding the collection is found to be null and need to be instantiated."

So in your Object say

```
class Student {
    private Map someMap = new LinkedHashMap(); //generics ignored for clarity
}
```

If you initialise your field with a LinkedHashMap instead of being null. I *think* castor will put entries into it directly and not recreate it. Is it possible to do this with your code?